# Having trouble with Async/Await Fetching from an API in React

Tags: javascript, fetch

Using React for this first time.
I'm trying to fetch from an api, but it keeps showing up as undefined.
I curl it on my command line and the data is received.

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/current.json";
        const { data } = await fetch(url);

        const modifiedData = data.map( (stateData) => ({
            state: stateData.state,
            pos: stateData.positive,
        }))

        this.setState({ data: modifiedData, loading: false });
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `json()` to get the json form of your data

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/current.json";
        const data = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

        const modifiedData = data.map((stateData) => ({
            state: stateData.state,
            pos: stateData.positive,
        }))

        this.setState({ data: modifiedData, loading: false });
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid promise and use pure `async/await` this can be alternative

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/current.json";

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json(); // call json() with await

  const modifiedData = data.map((stateData) => ({
    state: stateData.state,
    pos: stateData.positive,
  }));

  this.setState({ data: modifiedData, loading: false });
}
```